# Is there any way to change box shadow without passing a color?

Tags: html, css

Here is my issue. I have 2 css classes, my elements can have either

```
.classA{box-shadow:inset -2px 0px 0px 0px rgba(63,191,31,1);}
.classB{box-shadow:inset -2px 0px 0px 0px rgba(204,29,29,1);}
```

I wish to use a third class to change the inset but not the color

```
.classC{box-shadow:inset -10px 0px 0px 0px;}
```

That works (the shadow is here) but the color turns black. I would like to keep my original color.

How to change the shadow properties using **CSS ONLY** without losing the color?

Comment: I don't think `box-shadow` has child properties like `box-shadow-type` or `box-shadow-color` so you would have to redefine the whole property.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with @zgood. You can't target (with CSS) specific properties of `box-shadow`. You *may* be able to do this with JS, but that kind of defeats what you're trying to do with the third class.

Comment: as both comments above, when you inspect the element you cannot expand box-shadow property which means you cannot divide it like other property (border, font, margin, etc)

Comment: if the box-shadow is also the text color, then you can use : currentcolor. ... else , this could be usefull someday http://oocss.org/spec/css-variables.html . At this time preprocessor do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Box-shadow cannot be broken into parts like for example border can. But a trick you can use is that box-shadow inherits its color from the color attribute of the element.

```
<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="shadow box">
</div>

.box{
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.box.shadow{
  color: rgba(255,0,0,.3);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82z8r73o/

Comment: box-shadow: 1vw 1vw 5px #202C45;

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
box-shadow: 1vw 1vw 5px #202C45;
```